# Canvas draw image method prevents ondataavailable from firing

Tags: javascript, canvas, ip-camera, web-mediarecorder

Have a good day!

On localhost, I'm having a continuously changing `img` tag (I'll explain more at the end) and am using a canvas to draw the image on it, so I can use *MediaRecorder* to capture the video-like image and save it.

The code I'm using is this:

```
var canvas2 = document.getElementById("canV");
var ctx = canvas2.getContext("2d");

// Start of marking

update();
function update(){
 ctx.drawImage(videos[0],0,0,640,480);
 requestAnimationFrame(update);
}

// End of marking

var videoStream = canvas2.captureStream(10); 
videoStream.getVideoTracks()[0].requestFrame();
var mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(videoStream);
var chunks = [];
mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function(e) {
 chunks.push(e.data);
};
mediaRecorder.onstop = function(e) {
 var blob = new Blob(chunks, { 'type' : 'video/mp4' });
 chunks = [];
 var videoURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
 const video = document.createElement("video");
 video.src = videoURL;
 document.body.appendChild(video);
};
```

And I run the code below in console:

```
mediaRecorder.start(1000);

//After seconds

mediaRecorder.stop()
```

Note that the changing image is `videos[0]`;

I perceived that the `dataavailable` event is only fired when I stop the mediaRecorder.
So I tried drawing other things on the canvas to debug it. I changed the part marked as *"marking"* in the snippet to:

```
var colors = ["red", "blue", "green"];
setInterval(update, 100);

function update(){
  ctx.fillStyle = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 10, 10);
  ctx.drawImage(videos[0],0,0,640,480);
  requestAnimationFrame(update);
}
```

Until before, the blob is empty (I'm getting an error *GET blob:http://local:8080/dbe7d1ac-1d97-4d4a-8921-2a0daa10d31a net::ERR_REQUEST_RANGE_NOT_SATISFIABLE*) but after running this, I had a black background in the video generated, with a small red or blue or green square at the top left; it means the mediaRecorder records only the data when I run the stop method and si only recording the square not the drawImage, though; it still prevents dataavailable from firing.

Although, when I removed `ctx.drawImage(videos[0],0,0,640,480);` the event mentioned fires as expected.

So here comes two question, why the video doesn't show the changing image and why the draw image method prevents mediaRecorder from firing dataavialable event?

**FURTHER INFORMATION**
The changing image actually is an IP Webcam (DroidCam on an android) and the source of that image is something like `http://192.168.223.101:8080/video?640x480` and the image is actually a streaming camera in my cellphone.

Is it possible to be due to CORS or something?

And I'm not getting any more errors except the one I mentioned.

Any helps would be appreciated!

Comment: What browser are you testing on?

Comment: Where is `videos` defined?

Comment: The code works as expected here.

Comment: videos is defined in the same file; I'm using Chrome version Version 122.0.6261.71

Comment: Your code works re `ondataavailable` event firing https://plnkr.co/edit/l636QT9FWiQh8f4F?open=lib%2Fscript.js. Make sure your image source is decoded before drawing to the canvas. AFAIK Chrome doesn't support `video/mp4` for `MediaRecorder`.

Comment: Yes your source image needs to be served with the proper cross origin headers so that when you draw it on your canvas it doesn't taint it and the recorder can keep reading from the canvas.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts; it was indeed due to CORS and I was capable of debugging it; thanks